# Graph multiple plots for different values of parameters in R

Tags: r, plot, curve, par

I want to graphically explore a range of parameters for the given set of equations.

```
a = 1
b = 0.5
c = 0.8
d = 0.1
e = 0.6
f = 0.7
g = 0.2



y1 = function(x){c + b * x + d+ g+ f}
y2 = function(x){a + c + b^2 * x + e + g}

curve(y1, from = 0, to = 100, n = 100, xlim = c(-100, 100), ylim =c(-100,100), col = "grey")
    par(new = TRUE)
    curve(y2, from = 0, to = 100, n = 100, col = "orange")
```

I want to visualize how the graphs change for a = 0 to 100 (with increments of 2, so 0, 2, 4,...100) for given value of other parameters. I want to plot 50 graphs each with a different value of a all in one panel, or say 5 rows with 10 plots each. How to write this without huge blocks of the code (i.e. without repeating the plot code 50 times)?

Comment: can you clairfy your question? it is better to ask one clear questiuon, rather than several.

Comment: I hope the edits help now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have the knowledge to do this in base R, but it could be done in ggplot (and presumably base R, too) by precalculating the results in a source table.

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)

b = 0.5
c = 0.8
d = 0.1
e = 0.6
f = 0.7
g = 0.2

df <- tibble(
  x = rep(-100:100, 51),
  a = rep(seq(0, 100, by = 2), each = 201),
  y1 = c + b * x + d + g + f,
  y2 = if_else(x >= 0,
           a + c + b^2 * x + e + g,
           NA_real_)
)



ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1), color = "grey") +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2), color = "orange") +
  facet_wrap(~a, labeller = label_both) +
  # To simulate "Base R" theme
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=12),
             panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
             panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
             strip.background = element_blank()
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the line `x = rep(-100:100, 51)`,
  `a = rep(seq(0, 100, by = 2), each = 201)` ?

Comment: Those create a table with 1 row for every combination between x and a. `x = rep(-100:100, 51)` creates a vector that repeats the sequence from -100 to 100, 51 times. So it counts through 201 integers (-100 to 100), then repeats that another 50 times. `a = rep(seq(0, 100, by = 2), each = 201)` counts from 0 to 100 by 2's, but the "each" means that it copies each value 201 times. So it sets a = 0 201 times, then a = 2 201 times, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify. If I want the x-axis to stretch from 0 to 8, and a to take values from 0 to 1 --- I did `x = rep(0:8, 51),a = rep(seq(0, 1, by = 0.02), each = 8)`. But I get an error saying Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Comment: 0:8 is nine values, might that be it? BTW, there are two kinds of errors: 1) off-by one errors. <endjoke>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Hahahahaha. Good one :)